# Generating highly customized dynamic PDF file

Tags: django, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, html-pdf, django-wkhtmltopdf

I have a requirement to generate a report in PDF format. The report is having some graphics (graphs, charts, etc). All of these dynamics - value of graph and charts will change based on the user input.

Currently I another similar working thing using https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf. So I am trying to implement this as well using same technology. I am not able to proceed ahead - lot of blockers.

Issue is sometime some javascript is not working with wkhtmltopdf, sometime some particular styles are not working, etc etc.

For example :

This https://codepen.io/umr55766/pen/WNQPVXG

```
is getting converted to pdf correctly.
```

[image]

Whereas, this https://codepen.io/umr55766/pen/QWjYeOG

```
is not getting converted correctly.
```

[image]

I need help with following this:

1. If this is not the right question for this platform - where should I go ?
2. Am I missing something in wkhtmltopdf ? How can I make it working seamlessly ? Any links, resources, much appreciated!
3. Would you suggested any other tool/tech to generate highly customized PDF ?